# Why is JS submitting form to the wrong URI endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

I am trying to submit a form in JS, however I believe the endpoint URI specified in the `action` attribute does not consider the relative path of the HTML document.
I think this may be due to the fact that the JS script and HMTL document are not located in the same directory. The HTML doc is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    student name:
    <input type="text" class="studentName"></input>
    <button type="button" id="addStudentButton">Add</button>
</div>
    <script src="/cdn/scripts/class/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The imported JS script `index.js` is:

```
const addButton = document.getElementById('addStudentButton')
addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const studentName = document.getElementsByClassName('studentName')[0]

  const form = document.createElement('form')
  const element1 = document.createElement('input')

  form.method = 'POST'
  form.action = '/api/create'

  element1.name = 'student'
  element1.value = studentName.value
  form.appendChild(element1)

  document.body.appendChild(form)
  form.submit()
})
```

When the form is submitted I get the following error response in chrome:

```
Cannot POST /api/create
```

This is because it should instead POST to `/class/api/create`, so I figured I should change the form attribute `action` accordingly to:

```
form.action = '/class/api/create'
```

however I then get the error response:

```
Cannot POST /class/class/api/create
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is?

Comment: check your server-side is there post routes /class/class/api/create exists and paste code snippet of server code also.

Comment: @SatishGupta I have a post route for /class/api/create on my server, however the client posts to /api/create, for some reason it doesn't include /class

Comment: action add /class/api/create into the current url, if you have full URL then use it e.g http://yourdomain.com/<uri_path>

Comment: I would like to specify the relative URL address in the action attribute, not the absolute address.

Comment: You need a leading `/` on the path you specify.  That's the only way you can control it.  Otherwise, it adds the path of your page URL to what you specify.